# GeoPandas not reading shapefiles

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I'm having an issue with reading in shapefiles using Geopandas (have tried multiple ones from different sources in case the old ones have been corrupted). Below is my code snippet:

```
print("Reading in GIS Shapefile Data")
county_fp = (r'C:\Users\Lamont\Downloads\USA_Counties\USA_Counties.shp')
county_mp_df = gpd.read_file(county_fp)
```

Here's the error that I am getting:
NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not themselves provide the array interface

I've tried setting the encoding as well and that has not worked out. This is really annoying trying to track this down and I've used similar code for years.

Comment: This may be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347010/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-read-a-file-in-geopandas-included-datasets